# Create table with multiple Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, primary-key

When I try to create a table with 1 PK & 3 FK. But faced the below error.

**Code 1**:

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Rent
(
    cardID number,
    itemID varchar2(10),
    appropriationDate DATE,
    returndate DATE,

    CONSTRAINT Rent_pk  
        PRIMARY KEY(cardID, itemID),
    CONSTRAINT Rent_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (cardID) REFERENCES Card(cardID),
    CONSTRAINT Rent_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES Book(bookID),
    CONSTRAINT Rent_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES Videos(videoID)
);
```

Error:

> Error report
>
> ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
> 02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
>
> *Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table.
> *Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS catalog view

**Code 2**:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    employeeID number,
    name varchar2(40),
    address varchar2(40),
    empphone number(9),
    paycheck number(8,2),
    username varchar2(10),
    password varchar2(20),
    cardnumber number,
    branchname varchar2(40),

    CONSTRAINT Employees_pk 
        PRIMARY KEY(employeeID),
    CONSTRAINT Employees_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (cardnumber) REFERENCES Card(cardID),
    CONSTRAINT Employees_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (branchname) REFERENCES Branch(bname)
);
```

> Error report
>
> ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
> 02264. 00000 -  "name already used by an existing constraint"
> *Cause:    The specified constraint name has to be unique.
> *Action:   Specify a unique constraint name for the constraint.

How do I add multiple foreign keys? Please help me

Comment: For your second example (same is also present in first example): you **cannot** call all your foreign key constraint the same - use different and meaningful / speaking names - `FK_Employees_Card` and `FK_Employees_Branch` for instance

Comment: and for the first all referenced column from other tables , need to be primary Key, UNIque or INDex/KEY and if you defined a combined Kex/Index then the reference must also all both columns in it

Answer (score 3):

You have three issues.

First, you're trying to name two constraints with the same name. Constraints must have unique names within a schema.

Second, at least one of your parent tables doesn't have a PK or UK constraint on the column you want to use for enforcement. Check for unique constraints on Card(CardId), Book(BookID), Videos(VideoID) and create whichever one(s) are missing.

Lastly, you don't want two foreign keys on the same column. It will enforce an *and* condition requiring the child key to be present in *both* parent tables.

This last issue is a data modeling problem. To resolve it, you have two options:

1. Don't use `ItemId` in your Rent table. Instead, **split out `videoId` and `bookId`** and `CHECK` constraint to ensure at least one is `NOT NULL`:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Rent
   (
       cardID number,
       bookID varchar2(10),
       videoID varchar2(10),
       appropriationDate DATE,
       returndate DATE,
    CONSTRAINT Rent_uk  
        UNIQUE KEY(cardID, bookID, videoID),
    CONSTRAINT Rent_Card_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (cardID) REFERENCES Card(cardID),
    CONSTRAINT Rent_Book_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (bookId) REFERENCES Book(bookID),
    CONSTRAINT Rent_Video_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (videoId) REFERENCES Videos(videoID),
    CONSTRAINT chk_bookorvideo  CHECK ((bookId IS NOT NULL OR videoId IS NOT NULL) AND NOT (bookId IS NULL AND videoId IS NULL))
   ```

   );

   I'm not a fan of this approach because I don't like having two parent relationships if I can avoid it, it requires a special `CHECK` constraint to enforce non-nullity and exclusivity. Plus in your case, since your `itemID` was part of your PK, you'd have to change your primary key to a unique key and place it on two nullable columns instead of one non-nullable column (which means it'd probably be better to create a surrogate key (`RentId`) for the PK instead. What you have isn't a good PK definition anyway, because it won't allow the same CardId to rent the same ItemId more than once, meaning a patron can only check out each book once in their life-time, or until they get issued a new card).
2. Alternatively (and this would be my definite preference), create a **supertype table called `Item`** and make `Book` and `Video` **subtype** tables to it, enforced with a foreign key:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Item
    (
        itemID varchar2(10),
        itemType varchar2(10) CHECK (itemType IN ('Book', 'Video')),
        commonItemAttributeColumns...,
        CONSTRAINT pk_item PRIMARY KEY (itemID)
    );

   ALTER TABLE Book ADD CONSTRAINT fk_book_item FOREING KEY (BookId) REFERENCES Item(itemID);

   ALTER TABLE Video ADD CONSTRAINT fk_video_item FOREING KEY (VideoId) REFERENCES Item(itemID);
   ```

Now you only need a single foreign key in your `Rent` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Rent
(
    cardID number,
    itemID varchar2(10),
    appropriationDate DATE,
    returndate DATE,
    CONSTRAINT Rent_pk  
        PRIMARY KEY(cardID, itemID),
    CONSTRAINT Rent_Card_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (cardID) REFERENCES Card(cardID),
    CONSTRAINT Rent_Item_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (itemId) REFERENCES Item(ItemID)
);
```

One last note, I kept your convention with mixed-cased but just be aware that unless you override it with double quotes (*not* a good idea) Oracle objects are case-insensitive. They will be converted to all caps in the dictionary, causing you to lose visual separation between words. So it's better to use underscores to separate words than camel case.

Answer (score 2):

The error `ORA-02270` is telling you that the foreign key you're trying to create doesn't match a unique or primary key constraint in the referenced table.

In your code, the `itemID` field is referencing both the `Book` and `Videos` tables. It appears that you are trying to enforce that `itemID` can be either a `bookID` or `videoID`. This is not directly supported by standard SQL foreign key constraints.

You can work around this by creating separate tables for `RentBook` and `RentVideo`, or by introducing a separate type field in the `Rent` table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Rent
(
    cardID number,
    itemID varchar2(10),
    itemType varchar2(10) CHECK (itemType IN ('Book', 'Video')),
    appropriationDate DATE,
    returndate DATE,

    CONSTRAINT Rent_pk  
        PRIMARY KEY(cardID, itemID),
    CONSTRAINT Rent_card_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (cardID) REFERENCES Card(cardID),
    CONSTRAINT Rent_book_fk 
        CHECK (itemType = 'Book' AND itemID IN (SELECT bookID FROM Book)),
    CONSTRAINT Rent_video_fk 
        CHECK (itemType = 'Video' AND itemID IN (SELECT videoID FROM Videos))
);
```

The error `ORA-02264` is telling you that constraint names must be unique within a schema. In the given code, you've used the name `Employees_fk` for both foreign key constraints, which is causing the error. Simply give them unique names like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    employeeID number,
    name varchar2(40),
    address varchar2(40),
    empphone number(9),
    paycheck number(8,2),
    username varchar2(10),
    password varchar2(20),
    cardnumber number,
    branchname varchar2(40),

    CONSTRAINT Employees_pk 
        PRIMARY KEY(employeeID),
    CONSTRAINT Employees_card_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (cardnumber) REFERENCES Card(cardID),
    CONSTRAINT Employees_branch_fk 
        FOREIGN KEY (branchname) REFERENCES Branch(bname)
);
```